# hide/unhide Post not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to hide a post with  **facebook-graph-api**.

$mydata = $facebook->api("/$UId_$posId",'POST',array('access_token' => $page_access_token,'is_hidden'=>'true'));

but am getting this error:

Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Invalid post id

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704409/how-to-hide-page-post-using-facebook-api/18569846